# investigating indexeddb storage in chromium browser and cleaning it from javascript

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, microsoft-edge, chromium, indexeddb

I am developing `PWA` app where storage usage (for offline data) is a crucial factor to success. After checking the storage information in debug tools I see that more than `1 gb`(**!!!**) is consumed by the `indexedDb`!

[image]

I went to investigate further, and it seems like this storage is being shared between all `localhost` environments: `https://localhost:4173/`, `https://localhost:3000/`. Same consumption is reported by both sites.

I went ahead and clicked on "**Clear site data**" button, but only 1mb of data was cleared (there are literary no databases or caches or anything like that for both websites). I even restarted the browser

I also ran the filesystem analyzer and was able to determine that this is in fact these 2 addresses that consume the space. `522.9mb` each

[image]

In PWA users are able to see the space consumption estimate through the `navigator.storage` API:

```
    if ("storage" in navigator && "estimate" in navigator.storage) {
        return navigator.storage.estimate();
      }
```

So when the space grows more than let's say 100mg and users want to clean-up some space - it should be possible to clear it from the UI of the app.. right not I can't even clear it manually using the browser tools. I view this as a huge problem to both the customer experience and technical implementation if this space can not be freed..

So my question is - what kind of data is in there and more importantly how do I clear it from the `javascript`? Because I have done the cleaning for both the 4173 and 3000 ports manually and nothing has changed..

Any advices or solutions are welcomed. I am using the "Ms Edge v100" chromium-based browser.

Comment: I only find `deleteDatabase()` to clear indexedDB. I think the data in indexedDB is related to how you use indexedDB in your app. Please follow the [Best Practices for Using IndexedDB](https://web.dev/indexeddb-best-practices/), especially paragraph **Keeping your app performant**. *As a general rule, reads and writes to IndexedDB should not be larger than required for the data being accessed.*

Answer (score 1):

Did you try?

```
let req = indexedDB.deleteDatabase(databaseName);
req.onsuccess = function () {
    console.log("Deleted database successfully");
};
req.onerror = function () {
    console.log("Couldn't delete database");
};
req.onblocked = function () {
    console.log("Couldn't delete database due to the operation being blocked");
```

Also you can manually delete it like this:

[image]

Comment: yes. When you click on "clear site data" it removes all of the website assets. Including caches, databases (localstorage + indexed db + others) as well as cookies. Everything is removed. No data is present. I even restarted the browser. Sure I can implement database drop as you suggest. This was my plan.. But if there is nothing to drop anymore but the app still occupies 1gb of data then it's a huge problem that is not going to go away by drops. This is why I am looking for alternative solutions :) Or any at all that work.